# selective and dynamic monetization in Apigee

Tags: apigee

I do not want to charge customers for few of the websites they browse and instead pass on this charge to the other party say the website owner .

Kindly let me know how to implement this , like how to know what website the customer is viewing and dynamically don't charge him for this usage.

I am totally new to monetization stuff ,so any help to start with  in this regards is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is that the website owner would be set up as your partner and issued an API Key. The calls coming in to the Monetized API are then counted and the usage is tracked via API Key.  For more details check out these docs: http://apigee.com/docs/monetization/content/monetize-api-products

Comment: If [this is you](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tejaswiniravindra), then you should disclose your affiliation in your answers and probably also in your user profile.